# add GD Star Rating's to buddypress comments

Tags: plugin-gd-star-rating

I am trying to add GD Star Rating's to wordpress comments but struggling to add them to the comment form

There is an explanation here but the code snippet is corrupted -http://www.placementedge.com/blog/gd-star-rating-comment-integration-with-wordpress-3-0/

The code I need to add to the comment form is wp_gdsr_comment_integrate_standard_rating

Does anyone have any ideas on how this would be added and the code to use?

Many thanks for your help